# Remove the Notification Center icon from the Menu Bar

Tags: macos

I would like to remove the Notification Center icon like I could in Yosemite.

I'd like to not see it in the menu bar (to the right of the spotlight icon).

Comment: How did you do it in Yosemite? What happens when you try that method now? It might be helpful if you post some screen shots and elaborate more.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious the OP wants to modify the icons in their Mac menu bar, no? @CalebKleveter

Comment: @bmike, it wasn't obvious until I read your comment. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: In yosemite the command: launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist  removed the icon. In El Capitan the above command simply disables the icon from working but leave it in the menu. @CalebKleveter

Answer (score 5):

So you can easily disable it with

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist; killall NotificationCenter
```

You can remove the icon with

```
sudo rm /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app/Contents/Resources/menuitemNormal.pdf
```

but the blank space will remain.  There is an app called Bartender I've seen a few people promoting to fix this issue.

Comment: Bartender cannot remove the Notification Center, it just tells you to do the same thing as what @mulquin suggested.

Comment: Is it possible to remove that blank space yet?

Answer (score 4):

To follow on @walshie4's answer above: The second command will not execute with El Capitan due to [System Integrity Protection](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/).

You must first boot into recovery mode, start a terminal and execute the following:

```
csrutil disable; reboot
```

Also note that after deleting the menuItemNormal.pdf file, the area is still a blank clickable space.