# Hide Notification Center button from menu bar in High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, notifications

How do I get rid of the Notification Center button in the menu bar in High Sierra?

It's that one in the far right:

[image]

I'd like the space it occupies to disappear too. Apparently it used to be possible to hide the icon but the space would remain.

Also, I want to continue using the Notification Center; currently I access it with a gesture on my trackpad.

The answers to [Remove the Notification Center icon from the Menu Bar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212393/remove-the-notification-center-icon-from-the-menu-bar) do not work for me in High Sierra.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove the Notification Center icon from the Menu Bar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212393/remove-the-notification-center-icon-from-the-menu-bar)

Comment: With the introduction of [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899), making changes like this has gotten a wee bit more complicated. The answer by walshie4 shows how to disable it. The answer by mulquin indicates you must disable SIP to make the change with launchctl that governs the appearance of this icon. A blank space will remain in that location, however - only the icon is removed. **Remember to re-enable SIP when you are finished!**

Comment: @IconDaemon which answer are you referring to? **edit** oh you were talking about SIP, I already know how to disable SIP. Disabling SIP is not the answer to this question though.

Comment: Do you want to disable notifications as well?  or just remove icon?

Comment: @jmh just hide the icon, I'd like to be able to access the notifications centre by swiping on my trackpad

Comment: The answers were out of order in the posting. You disable SIP, run the `launchctl` command, then re-enable SIP. Does the `launchctl` command not disable the icon from appearing?

Comment: @IconDaemon `launchctl unload` just stopped notification centre from working but left the icon untouched. I want notification centre to work, and I want to hide the icon. The answer basically does the opposite of what i want.

Comment: If you find an answer let me know, because I looked into this before and it didn't appear to be possible any more.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bartender app](https://www.macbartender.com/) allows you to hide and rearrange menu bar icons - it may work for you.