# How to hide Spotlight in menu bar but keep the ⌘Space keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, spotlight, high-sierra, menu-bar

I want to hide spotlight from the menu bar

[image]

I never click this button.

---

So I followed the instructions [here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/02/02/disable-spotlight-remove-menu-bar/) and used this code to change the `Spotlight` file in some way:

```
sudo perl -pi -e 's|(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x47\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00)\x42\x40(\x00\x00\x80\x3f\x00\x00\x70\x42)|$1\x00\x00$2|sg' Spotlight
```

It hid the menu-bar icon, but it also disabled the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> keyboard shortcut that I use a lot.

Is there a way to hide the icon in the menubar but allowing the keyboard shortcut to work?

---

I just saw [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151586/how-do-i-hide-the-spotlight-icon-on-yosemite-but-keep-the-spotlight-functionali?rq=1) asking the same thing but for Yosemite.

The accepted answer doesn't work for me on High Sierra, and all the other answers suggest using third-party tools like Bartender which I don't want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide notification centre button from menu bar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306669/hide-notification-centre-button-from-menu-bar)

Comment: @fsb lmfao the questions are different so I don't think they're duplicates. Who knows, maybe the answers will be similar.

Comment: This question could probably be closed and the duplicate updated with your additional requirement.

Comment: @fsb why would I do that? This is no "additional" requirement, it's a separate question.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Best thing I could find is an app called Bartender

Comment: Have you tried dragging the Spotlight Icon off of the Menubar while holding down the Option Key this should remove the Icon from the Menubar (if Apple didn't change that) if this also stops the Shortcut from working (shouldn't if i remember correct) give Alfred (https://www.alfredapp.com) a try works like Spotlight but also has some other nice Features which Spotlight is Missing

Comment: Haven't found a way to hide it completely, but you can hold Cmd and then drag the spotlight button all the way to the left of the menu bar.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I know to do this is with a third party app like Bartender (https://www.macbartender.com). The app is used to hide pretty much any menu bar icon, and has a lot of great features. It's kind of a "must have" for and Mac Power User.